# Include a custom class in Xcode 11 Object Library

Tags: ios, xcode, uikit

I have written my own class which inherits UIView. This is marked as @IBDesignable and properties I want to include in the interface builder are marked as @IBInspectable.

This works with no issues if I add a UIView to my interface, and then set its custom class .. eg it renders how I expect, and my properties appear in the attributes inspector.

How can I add my class however to the object library so instead of adding a UIView to the interface, I am actually adding an instance of my view, with only my exposed attributes, and my attributes set as their defaults?

Searched through countless questions and articles online and can only find reference to creating an Xcode plugin, which is no longer supported.

I am a multi language programmer and only use Xcode for iOS/Swift work, and this is a standard feature available in other IDEs I use (VS, Android Studio, and Delphi) - I am assuming I am missing something which is maybe underdocumented somewhere - or is this a case of an oversight/missing feature in the IDE?

Comment: Sadly, what you've found via searching is correct. Xcode / Interface Builder has no support for "plugins" or adding custom objects to the object library (note that you *can* add custom code snippets, but that's, of course, no help with this task).

Comment: Cheers DonMag ... I did think as much from my searching, just seemed like an everyday thing so thought I may be missing something as XCode isn't my everyday IDE so not savvy in all the options/hidden helpers

Comment: Since you now know the answer could you delete the question so it doesn’t sit hanging open?

Comment: I can do. Still hoping there would be a work around or something in the XCode roadmap. Got nowhere with Apple Support on the subject. Oh well.

Comment: 2022 still no solution for this? :(